# Mature standard library for C

Tags: c, open-source, cross-platform

I'm looking for a library for C that gives me at least some of the things I really miss from C++ and the STL/Boost. (I have to use C, so please no "use C++" posts)

I need

1. dynamic strings (that grow and shrink automatically)
2. some sort of list (std::vector replacement)
3. something like stringstream (for type conversations & buffers)

Furthermore, it has to have a mature and Open Source implementation and it has to be platform independant (Windows, Linux and Mac are required to be supported).

Any recommendations?

Comment: Your question title is a misnomer; what you are after is a mature non-standard library for C.  The standard library for C does not provide what you request.

Comment: I'd think Jonathan is right, but I read  it.  Tell  me about a useable C datastructure library

Answer (score 14, accepted):

What about the [GLib](http://library.gnome.org/devel/glib/) from GTK?

Comment: It looks interesting, do you have any experience with it? Is it usable and not too complicated to get the hang of?

Comment: Sorry, I do not have any experience with it. AFAIK, The "native" way to wirte programs for GNOME is in C (not C++) with GLIB. Also, the author of the IRC client irssi (http://irssi.org) uses it.

So a lot of people are using it (not that this is implies high quality software in every case...)

Comment: glib is very easy to use. It's very consistent and one of the better "free" software libraries.

Comment: Seconded, or whatever. glib is excellent.

Comment: Ok, I think you guys convinced me, glib really seems to be exactly what I want (although quite a nightmare to compile under Windows). Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: There are precompiled packages for MSVC if you have some way of using such libraries with your C tool set you don't have to compile it yourself.

Answer (score 4):

I'd recommend the [Apache Portable Runtime](http://apr.apache.org/). It's reasonably small, portable, and powerful - powers the Apache httpd across multiple platforms, at least.

Answer (score 2):

You could always consider embedding a dynamic language runtime in your application. The [Lua](http://www.lua.org/) core is not large at all, provides data types that meet your requirements, is open source, and MIT licensed so it is compatible with both FOSS and commercial projects.

You wouldn't necessarily need to use code written in Lua to benefit, as its C API provides complete access to its data types and their values. However, you could later move some of the logic of your application into Lua, for the improved clarity of expression and other benefits of coding in a dynamic language with functions as first-class values.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Gnulib](http://www.gnu.org/software/gnulib/)